# Sum SQL Values Based On 20 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 20 tables with same column with several example as below :

```
Australian GP
DRIVER | Points
================
HAM    | 25
VET    | 20
RIC    | 15

Japanese GP
Driver | Points
==============
HAM    | 25
VET    | 20
RIC    | 15

Malaysian GP
Driver | Points
RIC    | 25
HAM    | 20
VET    | 15
```

I am planning to join all the 20 tables and all 20 driver datas as below for example :

```
Championship Standings
Driver   | Points
HAM      | 70
VET      | 65
RIC      | 50
```

Based on intense googling and massive confusion (I am bad at SQL since I have no spare time to learn outside my college), I have conclusion to use inner join and subquery such as below (which I don't know is it correct or a laughstock):

```
select driverid, point
from usa a, russia b, japan c
    inner join (select driverid as Driver, sum(point) group by points);
```

I also thought that do I have to write 20 inner joins (as per example below) to connect the driver values between the tables?
(I created a table for Driver which contains driverid as primary key. All table that used to write points use foreign key from driver table)

Really really appreciate any helps regarding this case

Comment: You want to not have 20 tables.

Comment: All 20 tables should be contained in **one** table with *country* indicator field: Efficient and scalable storage. Maintainable queries.

Comment: @Bill S, kindly check my updated answer as well, sorry, I can't test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want union all`:

```
select driver, sum(points)
from ((select driver, points from usa) union all
      (select driver, points from russia) union all
      . . .
     ) c
group by driver;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select * From Table1

UNION ALL

Select * From Table2

UNION ALL

Select * From Table3
.
.
.
GROUP BY Driver
```

Where Table1, Table2, Table3 and so on are the names of your actual tables

Comment: This just combines the records, but it's not summing as the OP asked.